# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'TNode {aka struct SNode}'

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I've seen many questions about this before on here. But my program has the same problem.

this is the struct i've made

```
struct SVolo{
        float orariopart;
        float orarioarr;
        char pospartenza[MAX];
        char posarrivo[MAX];
        char code[COD];
        int nposti;
        TList mappa;
        };
```

and in the header file i defined

```
typedef struct SNode TNode;
typedef TNode *TBST;
```

Ok so now i need a function that would give me the subtree i want

```
TBST search_fly(TBST voli,char codice[COD]){
    if (voli==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(info_uguali(voli->info,codice)){
    return voli;
        }
    if(info_maggiore(voli->info,codice)){
     voli->right=search_fly(voli->right,codice);
     return voli;
    }else{
        voli->left=search_fly(voli->left,codice);
        return voli;
    }
       }
```

the last function you need to know about  is

```
void update_map(TVolo unvolo,TList mapppa){
         unvolo.mappa=mapppa;
     }
```

when i call it in the main i call it in the following way

```
TBST tmp;
tmp=search_fly(voli,codice);
update_map(tmp->info,map);// and here's the error in the title
```

```
struct SNode {
    TVolo info;
    struct SNode *left;
    struct SNode *right;

};
```

```
struct SNodo{
    TUser info;
    struct SNodo *link;
};
typedef struct SNodo TNodo;
typedef TNodo *TList;
```

I really don't understand what's wrong with the TNode (aka struct SNode) declaration. Also i used that struct for other functions and parts of the code and it gave me no errors . So i guess something is wrong in the subfunctions or something.

Comment: You can use the opaque type as long as you only need pointers and don't need to access what is inside.  Once you need to access structure members, you must have the complete structure definition available.

Comment: What you mean how's the struct not aviable i don't get it

Comment: `struct SNode` is not defined anyplace. `TList mappa;` has no way of knowing it size.

Comment: Provide the definition of all your data structures (e.g. `SNode`, `TList`, ...). Also, you haven't showed how `map` is declared in the last piece of code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica SNode is declared in the source file

Comment: Your code isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). It looks as though you have a header, and two or more source files. The header doesn't contain the structure definitions — the code which contains `struct SomeTag { … };` (where the braces and the bit in between are crucial). One of the source files does contain the structure definitions. The code in that file can dereference the pointers to the structure. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The other source files do not know about the details of what's in the structure; those files cannot dereference the pointers — that is use `ptr->member` to access the data in a structure.  Either provide access functions to get at the data inside a structure, or put the structure definitions into the header (and remove them from the source file), or put the code that needs to know the structure definition into the source file where the structure is defined.